# How to use two java.lang.Runtimes in the same Method?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I want to use two `Runtime` in same method. The second  uses the result of the first. I return  the results of  in two files (`*.txt`). The result of execution of the first is ok, but the file of the second is empty.

The code used is given below:

```
public void applicationpackage() {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    new String[] { "/bin/sh", "-c",
                            "ls " + pathPackage + "/*.apk" });
            process.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    process.getInputStream()));
            File f = new File(pathPackage + "/packagename.txt");
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(f, "UTF-8");
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while ((line != null)) {
                System.out.println(line);
                applicationPackage.add(line);
                writer.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{
                        "/bin/sh", "-c", "cut -d. -f2,3 <<<" + line
                });
                p.waitFor();
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())); 
                File file = new File(pathPackage +"/application.txt");
                PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
                String l = r.readLine();
                while(l!= null){
                    w.println(l);
                    w.println("toto");
                    l = r.readLine();
                }

                name+= "cut -d. -f2,3 <<<" + line +" &";

                System.out.println("toto" + name);
            }
            System.out.println("toto" + name);
            writer.close();


        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1) { }

}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I have no idea what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: can you highlight the problematic code ?

Comment: I use a first process to get a list of name from a file. the second is used to creat an other file but to make a cut for each line.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is empty, it usually means your `PrintWriter` has not got autoflush set, or you have not closed the writer. The last reference to `w` is `w.println("toto");`. Add `w.close()` to your code.

Also when you instantiate a `PrintWriter` you should pass in a boolean value at the constructor level to indicate that the `PrintWriter` should flush after every operation.

Comment: I closed it but. it is not a problem if we dont do that. concerning PrintWriter is the some for the first process. for the first every thing is ok.